# Why are images not showing up?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, dhtml

There is problem with displaying images on pages in IE9: images are shown OK in Firefox and other browsers, but do not show up in IE9. In Firefox is shown all images on main page, but in IE9 only one image shown. Clicking on that image load page where detailed images are not displayed too.
http://jurmalarealestate.ru/doma/

Probably, this issue is due to IE9 can no properly size images when width specified in percents.

How to fix this issue? Perhaps, there is a reason why they chosen scale images with browser, which is not a good way to do.

Answer (score 2):

Set a proper `DOCTYPE` so IE will know how to interpret your size attributes. Additionally better use the `style` attribute to set those values instead, like

```
<a style="width:162px; height:120px;" ....
```

Comment: Adding DOCTYPE helped for aboved page, but not works for other pages with detailed info: [sample](http://tiny.cc/opjjhw)

Comment: The pages with detailed info don't have DOCTYPE either .... all your html pages should have a proper DOCTYPE.

Comment: yes I added `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` to mentioned pages, tested page copy, but it does not show images(these images have 'width' attribute specified in percents).

Comment: as far as I can see your sample page still doesn't have a DOCTYPE

Comment: I mean I copied this html page and tested it locally from my drive with applied changes(not on live server).